# ZF2 Captcha validation always is Valid

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form

I added A Captcha to my form
my form is created in method of my class

this is the method definition

```
  public function generateFormAndValidate($urlcaptcha = null)
  {
        $form = new \Zend\Form\Form();
        $formInputFilter = $form->getInputFilter();
        $inputFactory = new \Zend\InputFilter\Factory();

        $dirdata = './data';

        //pass captcha image options
        $captchaImage = new CaptchaImage(  array(
                'font' => $dirdata . '/fonts/arial.ttf',
                'width' => 250,
                'height' => 100,
                'dotNoiseLevel' => 40,
                'lineNoiseLevel' => 3)
        );




        $captchaImage->setImgDir($dirdata.'/captcha');
        $captchaImage->setImgUrl($urlcaptcha);




        //add captcha element...
        $form->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Captcha',
            'name' => 'captcha',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Please verify you are human',
                'captcha' => $captchaImage,
            ),
        ));


        $formInputFilter->add ( $inputFactory->createInput ( array(
            'name' => 'captcha',
           // 'required' => 'true'

            ))
        );
  }
```

and in controller:

```
       // ......
        $form->setData($post);

        if ($form->isValid()) {

        }
        else {

        }
        //....
```

my captcha Image showing correctly ,and captcha code is posted and I checked Session And Everything is ok  
 but `$form->isValid` return True any time and even i put captcha input empty or use any character it returns  `True` anyway
i guess `isValid` method not checked captcha at all .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Controller:

```
//...
$form->setData($post);
$form->setInputFilter($form->getInputFilter());  //You missed this line
if ($form->isValid()) {
// ...
```